# An error occurred while creating the inverse form: Call to a member function isAttributeRequired() on null?

Tags: yii2, active-form

please help me deal with this problem, after creating the inverse form on yii2, this error occurred:

```
Call to a member function isAttributeRequired() on null
1. in C:\Users\acer\OSPanel\domains\medicalyii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\widgets\ActiveField.php at line
/**
 * Adds aria attributes to the input options.
 * @param $options array input options
 * @since 2.0.11
 */
protected function addAriaAttributes(&$options)
{
    if ($this->addAriaAttributes) {
        if (!isset($options['aria-required']) && $this->model->isAttributeRequired($this->attribute)) {
            $options['aria-required'] = 'true';
        }
        if (!isset($options['aria-invalid'])) {
            if ($this->model->hasErrors($this->attribute)) {
                $options['aria-invalid'] = 'true';
            }
        }
    }
}

2. yii\base\ErrorHandler::handleFatalError()
```

I can not understand what this problem is connected with .... This is how my form looks in the view:

```
<?php
                    $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                        'id' => 'appointment_form',
                        'fieldConfig' => [
                            'options' => [
                                'tag' => 'span',
                                'class' => 'input input--kohana'
                            ],
                            'template' => '{input}{label}',
                            'inputOptions' => ['class' => 'input__field input__field--kohana'],
                            'labelOptions' => [
                                'class' => 'input__label input__label--kohana',
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]);
                    ?>
                    <?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput(['inputOptions' => ['id' => 'input-29']])->label("<i class=\"icon-phone5 icon icon--kohana\"></i><span class=\"input__label-content input__label-content--kohana\">" . $model->getAttributeLabel('Your Name') . "</span>") ?>
                    <?= $form->field($model, 'email')->textInput(['inputOptions' => ['id' => 'input-30']])->label("<i class=\"icon-dollar icon icon--kohana\"></i><span class=\"input__label-content input__label-content--kohana\">" . $model->getAttributeLabel('Email Address') . "</span>") ?>
                    <span class="last"><?= $form->field($model, 'phone')->textInput(['inputOptions' => ['id' => 'input-31']])->label("<i class=\"icon-phone5 icon icon--kohana\"></i><span class=\"input__label-content input__label-content--kohana\">" . $model->getAttributeLabel('Phone Number') . "</span>") ?></span>
                    <?= $form->field($model, 'date')->textInput(['inputOptions' => ['id' => 'datepicker']])->label(false) ?>
                    <!-- ОСТАЛЬНЫЕ ПОЛЯ ФОРМЫ  -->
                    <?= $form->field($model, 'body')->textInput(['inputOptions' => ['id' => 'texterea']])->label("<i class=\"icon-new-message icon icon--kohana\"></i><span class=\"input__label-content input__label-content--kohana\">" . $model->getAttributeLabel('Message') . "</span>") ?>
                    <?= Html::submitButton('Submit'); ?>
                    <?php
                    ActiveForm::end();
                    ?>
```

Controller:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    /* Создаем экземпляр класса */
    $model = new AppointmentForm();
    /* получаем данные из формы и запускаем функцию отправки contact, если все хорошо, выводим сообщение об удачной отправке сообщения на почту */
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->appointment(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'])) {
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('contactFormSubmitted');
        return $this->refresh();
        /* иначе выводим форму обратной связи */
    }  else {
    return $this->render('index');
    }
}
```

AppointmentForm.php Model

```
class AppointmentForm extends Model
{
public $name;
public $email;
public $phone;
public $date;
public $body;


/**
 * @return array the validation rules.
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        // name, email, subject and body are required
        [['name', 'email', 'phone', 'date', 'body'], 'required'],
        // email has to be a valid email address
        ['email', 'email'],
    ];
}

/**
 * Sends an email to the specified email address using the information collected by this model.
 * @param string $email the target email address
 * @return bool whether the model passes validation
 */
public function appointment($email)
{
    $content = "<p>Email: " . $this->email . "</p>";
    $content .= "<p>Name: " . $this->name . "</p>";
    $content .= "<p>Phone: " . $this->phone . "</p>";
    $content .= "<p>Date: " . $this->date . "</p>";
    $content .= "<p>Body: " . $this->body . "</p>";
    if ($this->validate()) {
        Yii::$app->mailer->compose("@app/mail/layouts/html", ["content" => $content])
            //->setTo($email)
            ->setTo('swallowsveta97@yandex.ru')
            ->setFrom([\Yii::$app->params['supportEmail'] => $this->name])
            //->setFrom([$this->email => $this->name])
            //->setFrom('swallowsveta97@yandex.ru')
            //->setFrom([\Yii::$app->params['supportEmail'] => $this->name])
            ->setPhone($this->phone)
            ->setDate($this->date)
            ->setTextBody($this->body)
            ->send();

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

I was searching for internet on the Internet for 2 days, but I never found it.
Please tell me if this error may be related?

Comment: in your actiionIndex  you don't pass the model to the form ...    .the code for view is for the view index.php  ..  or you have posted  not related  code ? explain better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the model to the view

```
return $this->render('index', ['model'=> $model ,]);
```

eg:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    /* Создаем экземпляр класса */
    $model = new AppointmentForm();
    /* получаем данные из формы и запускаем функцию отправки contact, если все хорошо, выводим сообщение об удачной отправке сообщения на почту */
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->appointment(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'])) {
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('contactFormSubmitted');
        return $this->refresh();
        /* иначе выводим форму обратной связи */
    }  else {
    return $this->render('index', ['model'=> $model,]);
    }
}
```